# Java : logic and operation (&&) on lambda expression allowed?

Tags: java, lambda

I dived into Java source code and found this:

file: Predicate.java.(The Predicate interface in java.util.functions package)

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);//logic and lambda expression and boolean expression??
}
default Predicate<T> negate() {
    return (t) -> !test(t);//I understand this, it returned a lambda expression.
}
```

So what does `return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t)` means? Actually, I may know what it means. But I just wonder this operation is allowed on lambda expression type? Please point me to syntax and grammar reference.

Thanks!

Comment: @daniu got it! I want to laugh at myself now. Haha.

Comment: Hope it can write a pair of braces to make it more explicit.

Comment: @Han make what more explicit? Code doesn’t get much simpler than this.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for voting anyway.

Comment: @HanXIAO don't vandalise the post by changing the context completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (t) -> {return test(t) && other.test(t);};
}
```

Note the braces can be removed for succinctness.

What confuses me is that I wrongly parsed the code `return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);` as the lambda expression `(t) -> test(t)` logic and `other.test(t)`. So I asked questions relating to types and operations.

Comment: how does this answer the question? you've asked "how is the logical and (&&) allowed on a lambda expression"  and then you post an answer about "succinctness"... btw you've added the braces which makes it less concise and succinct not vice versa.

Comment: @Aomine I am just confused by syntax and I have revised my answer.

Comment: Not only that @Aomine, but `return` is needed inside the curly braces to make it compile.

Comment: @Bohemian fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It returns a `Predicate` that first invokes its `test` method (via an implicit `this`) and if needed `other.test` method... A `Predicate` has a `test` method defined - the only one abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much asking "how is the logical and (&&) allowed on a lambda expression".

Firstly, the method `and` with the functionality (`return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);` as mentioned in the method documentation.

> Returns a composed predicate that represents a short-circuiting
>   logical AND of this predicate and another.

As for the aforementioned question, `Predicate<T>` represents a function taking a type `T` and *returning a boolean*, since both `test(t)` and `other.test(t)` return *boolean* it's completely acceptable to use the logical and (&&) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas can be hard to read, especially if you're new to them.  Sometimes it helps to expand it to a non-lambda.  When learning lambdas, I had to write the full anonymous class implementation first, then reduce it to a lambda.  Here's what the code you pasted would look like without lambdas, if it helps.

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return new Predicate<T>() {
        public boolean test(T t) {
            return this.test(t) && other.test(t);
        }
    };
}

default Predicate<T> negate() {
    return new Predicate<T>() {
        public boolean test(T t) {
            return !this.test(t);
        }
    };
}
```